# Download file from database via SSRS report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, report, custom-code

I have a report which gives a list of files after providing necessary info through filtering parameters like: name, document type, when created or modified etc. The list will give us file IDs and other fields.The basic query is:

`select IQID, NAME from TABLE_FILES where...`(list of conditions from parameters)

How can I download any of the file after clicking on some button/image/link?
Here is my visualization:

[image]

After clicking on download icon, it would call Custom VB Code somehow.
In that custom code I would use below query to get the BLOB (file) based on the File ID from the first column:

```
SELECT BLOB
FROM   TABLE_FILES
WHERE  IQID = ReportItems.txt_IQID.Value
```

Also, among the parameters I would give to the user one parameter option where they would have to state **download location**. This download location would be also passed somehow to the custom code.

I am not even sure if that's possible in SSRS.
Also, I don't know how to trigger Download Custom Code after clicking on some object (like picture or link).

Comment: Is it web application ?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get the question. This is the SSRS report which people run using Report Manager, so via internet browser (IE or Chrome).

Comment: Ok. You can create web page for report downloading and set the last column as link to this page.

Comment: I am not really following you. What does it give me? How will that help me in executing the download code (either VB or C#) and running SELECT query?